# How to know all events are rendered in fullcalendar v5?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am trying to update the `contentHeight` after all events are rendered in fullcalendar v5.

Regarding the old version of fullcalendar(v3), it has [eventAfterAllRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventAfterAllRender) method, but fullcalendar v5 doesn't have.

In `listView` mode, how to set `contentHeight` dynamically, if the `fc-list-table` is over a specific height?

In reality, the calendar list view mode should has scroll if the height is over 300px.

Comment: There's no direct equivalent to eventAfterAllRender in v5. It's been removed. But...I'm not sure I understand your issue - the calendar will normally scroll automatically if the events won't fit into the vertical space. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/OJbbRXY . It's unclear why you are trying to make extra adjustments. Can you give a demo showing the issue you're trying to resolve by re-setting the contentHeight?

Comment: @ADyson I just set the `contentHeight` as 300px, then let's say there is only one event, the height is 50px, then except the height, that's 250px which is empty but the calendar border height is 300px.

Comment: @ADyson You could just try to remove all events except one from the codepen, then the calendar has empty space. How to fit the calendar height to the event height? If the height is over 300px, then it should have a scroll.

Comment: `How to fit the calendar height to the event height?`...you can't. It won't auto-adjust like that. You always end up with a minimum height. But it will increase the height by scrolling, if it needs to. If you'd like to explore whether what you want can be added as an option, then your best bet is probably to [make a feature request](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features)

Comment: @ADyson I understand about the feature request. But for now, I want to do that even manually. So after rendering all events, get the `fc-list-table` height, after that, if it is under 300px, then the `contentHeight` option or `fc-view-harness` height can be auto. What do you think about this?

Comment: I thihk that a) hacking around with the CSS is liable to break things and you'd have to keep re-testing it if you upgrade your fullCalendar, even by a point version (although setting the contentHeight option through the API ought to be viable, I have no issue with that), and b) it's unlikely to be possible anyway since there's no eventAfterAllRender equivalent in v5.

Comment: I guess you _could_ make a hacky version where you use eventDataTransform to count the number of events being returned (or via events-as-a-function, if you use that) and then have another count in the individual event render hooks, and when that count equals the count of downloaded events, you could be sure they had all rendered, and fire off your function to check the height. Ugly, but maybe it would work, if you're really desperate to have this. Or you could contribute the feature code yourself, to speed up development of a proper option.

Comment: I think being able to set the calendar's height dynamically is crucial, because clients have different resolutions. When you want to use all the space you can get from the viewport, a fixed height like 300px does not make much sense. Neither does `auto` when you want to keep the calendar header sticky on top and avoid scrolling the entire page. I've illustrated this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66196848/getting-actual-height-of-fully-rendered-calendar-page-fullcalendar